# Vue bind function on dynamic html elements

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am using datatable and has to add render different html based on few checks and that's why vue code has lots of jQuery events. I was wondering is there any way to assign event on dynamic html elements.

Inside Data table columns object

```
render:function(data, type, full, meta) {
    let html = '<div class="catagory-checkbox">'
        + '<label>'
        + '<input id="' + data.LeadTrackingId + '" class="statusDetail" type="checkbox" />'
        + '<span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>'
        + '</label>'
        + '</div>';
    if(vm.isSuperAdmin)
        return html;

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do this. You're constructing html with string methods. This is not the way, and there's no need. [Use `template:`, not `render:`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) ***:-)***

Your code above should look like...

```
template : `
<div  v-if"isSuperAdmin" class="catagory-checkbox">'
   <label>
      <input :id="LeadTrackingId" class="statusDetail" type="checkbox" />'
      <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
   </label>
</div>
`
```

You can bind id like that, but do you need to? Good Vue code doesn't need ids on html elements.

Comment: Can you please provide a basic example of using above scenario?